# Oozie: multiple versions of the same custom java action

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I'm using Oozie 4.1.0. I have deployed a *custom action* which extends the Java action. Now I need to deploy **another version** besides this one. The XSD would be the *same* but there are changes in the action code.

I'd put the updated action into a custom package and would version the action XSD. I guess the type name should be also changed in the constructor of the custom action as this needs to be unique, as far as I judged the code. 
But then how can I refer to the same action name in my workflow XML which uses the new version?
What is the recommended way to handle versions?

Comment: Not able to understand it completely, But you need to have unique action names and their respective ***ActionExecutor implemented and configured in oozie-site.xml

Comment: I'd like to keep the action name (xml element name) the same but be able to control which version of the action class to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to solve this issue:

- One should deploy the new version of the jar (action) to Oozie
- the new XSD version should be added to the oozie-site.xml under
  oozie.service.SchemaService.wf.ext.schemas

During runtime one can change the actual Oozie action class that is associated to the given action. For this set **oozie.launcher.action.main.class** in the global configuration section in *workflow.xml*.
This will be available in the launcherConf object in `org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor#getLauncherMain`
which can be overridden in the custom action if further changes are needed.